# Diskless Workstations

Tags: boot

I want to run diskless booting with PXE.

The gotchas at the end of the Diskless-Howto[1] is quite long.

I am unsure how to get this done. Here are my current possible solutions:

- use debian live and not ubuntu
- use aufs [2]

The How-To states "confirmed to work with Ubuntu 12.04.". But maybe I am doing something wrong, I don't think it works this way for several diskless clients sharing one nfsroot.

What is the most painless way to get diskless workstations?

PS: I can't create the new tag "diskless". Please create and add it. Thank you.

1: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto

2: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash

Comment: Your 1st link tells you all you need to know(?) And don't expect it to go painless :+

Answer (score 0):

After numerous tries and work-arounds, I did get a diskless system to boot using http://www.serenux.com/2011/04/howto-create-a-diskless-workstation-that-boots-from-pxe-using-ubuntu/ as a guide. A couple of details that the author did not mention is the need to remove Network Manager and also to set the mount point in the initramfs.conf file. One problem that still needs resolving is how to have multiple machines mount the same file system.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.